# How to change hash /#/ for /#!/

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, hash

I'm working with wordpress and I'd like to change the url once you click any local link. I'm loading pages with ajax, that's why I want to do this.
 I could make the url change adding a hash between the "http://site.com/" and the loaded content /example-page/, the result: "http://site.com/#/example-page" and it loads the example page but I want to add the "!" mark to get "http://site.com/#!/example-page" [just like this theme](http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Gleam/) 
I'm using [jquery-hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin btw.
Please let me know what you think.

*This code was edited after solved, so this is the right code.*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $mainContent = $("#container"),
    siteUrl = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
    url = '';
  $(document).delegate("a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*=/wp-admin/]):not([href*=/wp-login.php]):not([href$=/feed/])", "click", function() {
    location.hash = '!' + this.pathname;
    return false;
  });
  $("#searchform").submit(function(e) {
    location.hash = 's/' + $("#s").val();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    url = window.location.hash.substring(3);
    if (!url) {
      return;
    }
    url = url + " #content";
    $mainContent.animate({opacity: "0.1"}).html('Please wait...').load(url, function() {
      $mainContent.animate({opacity: "1"});
    });
  });
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the site - our way of marking questions solved is to mark an answer accepted using the tick icon, rather than editing the question to say that it is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
location.hash = this.pathname;
```

to

```
location.hash = "#!" + this.pathname;
```

(strictly speaking you should have had the hash there before) and change

```
url = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

to

```
url = window.location.hash.substring(2);
```

and also change

```
location.hash = '?s=' + $("#s").val();
```

to

```
location.hash = '#!?s=' + $("#s").val();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Neil. Actually I found the same answer hehe.

Comment: location.hash = '?s=' + $("#s").val(); does not work for me :/

Comment: @CarlosSalas I've updated my answer, there was a mistake in the original version.